# how to handle 10 webrequests with Task.Any when the bandwhich is too slow

Tags: c#, algorithm, async-await

I'm querying asynchronously 10 webrequests using httpClient.GetAsync
and I'm using Task.Any to process data as soon as one of the 10 request finished downloading

the thing is, each 10 request takes around 2-3 seconds to download
and using Task.Any means my app is downloading in the same time the 10 webrequests

if my connection bandwidth is slow the processing of the data is delayed

the solution would be to download a few requests, for example 2 out of the 10 requests
and sleep the other 8 requests. Then keep waking up the rest of the webrequest while process the first webrequests.

I don't know how I would do it
for now, my code looks like this

```
private async void OnLaunchClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       var quotesTask = new List<Task<IEnumerable<Symbol>>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Symbols.Count(); i = i + SYMBOLS_PAGINATION_PER_REQUEST)
            {
                var input = new UserInput(userInput.Symbols.Skip(i).Take(SYMBOLS_PAGINATION_PER_REQUEST), userInput.StartDate, userInput.EndDate, userInput.Interval);

                quotesTask.Add(quotesQuery.GetSymbolsInternal(input, _cts.Token));
            }

       while (quotesTask.Count > 0)
            {
                Task<IEnumerable<Symbol>> quotesFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(quotesTask);
                quotesTask.Remove(quotesFinishedTask);

      // Update UI
      }
 }

public async Task<IEnumerable<Symbol>> GetSymbolsInternal(UserInput filteredInput, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (filteredInput == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filteredInput");

        string url = BuildUrl(filteredInput);

        logger.Debug(string.Format("Start downloading quotes: {0}\n{1}", 
                                filteredInput.Symbols.Select(a => a.Name).Join(","),
                                url));
        string content = await _webRequest.GetData(url, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        logger.Debug(string.Format("End downloading quotes: {0}", filteredInput.Symbols.Select(a => a.Name).Join(",")));

        var symbols = Parse(filteredInput.Symbols, content);

        return symbols;
    }

public class WebRequest
{
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public virtual async Task<string> GetData(string uri, CancellationToken token)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            else
                logger.Error("Unable to retrieve data from the following url: {0} - StatusCode: {1}", uri, response.StatusCode);
        }
        return result;     
    }

}
```

The goal is to speed up the download of 1 of the 10 webrequests in order to process the data and to update UI as soon as possible instead of downloading 10 webrequests in the same time with a limited bandwidth and have to update the UI several seconds later.

Comment: There is no `Task.Any` - can you show your real code?

Comment: There is no `Any` method on Task.  Do you mean `Task.WhenAny`?

Comment: oh yes, thats it, Task.WhenAny(). My bad !! ^^' Question Edited

Comment: omg already 2 downvote, I m gonna delete my question. The code I posted in my question is the only thing interesting. The rest of my code is about parsing the data, validating security, and a lot of things which has no interest for the problem I'm trying to solve. Do you rwant me to copy paste my 200 lines of codes?

Comment: No, but extracting the relevant portions of the *real code* can be beneficial.  Fixing fake code doesn't help anybody

Comment: @ReedCopsey code updated using 90% of my real code

Comment: Provided an answer that does what I believe you're after - it'll let you start N tasks at once, and only schedule the next as they come back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move this inside your loop:

```
int tasksToRunAtOnce = 3;
var quotesTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<Quote>>(); 
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
     quotesTasks.Add(GetQuotesAsync(i)); 

     if (i < tasksToRunAtOnce - 1)
         continue;

     var quotesFinished = await Task.WhenAny(quotesTasks);
     quotesTasks.Remove(quotesFinished);

     // process data for quotesTasks
     // update the UI
}

while(quoteTasks.Any())
{
     var quotesFinished = await Task.WhenAny(quotesTasks);
     quotesTasks.Remove(quotesFinished);

     // process data for quotesTasks
     // update the UI
}
```

Note that we skip the first elements, so this will start `tasksToRunAtOnce` tasks, then start awaiting so the 3rd won't fire until one of the first 2 completes, etc.

Comment: Just perfect, working like a charm ! Thanks a lot Mister @ReedCopsey !